# Replacing the entry point function results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I have following program in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Normal.\n");
  return 0;
}

int fff()
{
  printf("Fun!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I wanted to compile it so that when I run the program, it gives me "Fun!". I used following line to compile my program:

```
gcc deneme.c -e fff -o deneme
```

When I run program named "deneme", i got :

```
Fun!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, i got what I want, but do not understand "segmentation fault" part. What is the reason?

Comment: You're trying to specify `fff()` as an entry function, but the `-e` flag does not replace `main` -- it replaces `_start`, which is an assembly routine.

Comment: How can i compile it so that it gives me the same without "segmentaion fault" ?

Comment: Your entry function should be of type `void` and end with a call to `_exit(ret)`, where `ret` is the return code. You may also need to compile with `-nostartfiles`.

Comment: I did the type of fff to be void. Also, fff ends with " exit(1); " now. It exactly works, thanks a lot !

Comment: Cool, adding this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to specify `fff()` as an entry function, but the `-e` flag replaces the function `_start`, not main. You'll want to change the return type of `fff` to `void` and call `_exit` at the end of the function.

```
void fff()
{
    printf("Fun!\n");
    _exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u can use

```
gcc filename.c -o executable-filename
```

Comment: This answer is missing every possible point. The OP is asking about replacing the entry point function.